# How do i change iOS storyboard Interface Builder to show iPhone4 preview?

Tags: xcode

Currently I have to run it on a device, and I have no idea how to see a preview on the storyboard (for iphone4 VS iphone5)

I am using XCode 6

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This my first experience with Xcode coding for iOS, so I'm using Xcode 6 and I didn't find any of the widgets in @return-true answer.

I guess in Xcode 6 you're left with the options shown in the w-vs-h widget at the bottom of the storyboard:

[image]

Comment: I don't see anything like that:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/iemlga5m7wizcpc/Screenshot%202014-11-07%2009.18.48%282%29.png?dl=0

Comment: @Kamilski81 OK, I don't understand why. Notice that I using the final version of Xcode 6 in a recently created project type for iPhone, not a beta one. Also, I'm still on Mavericks.

Comment: This is not a preview, this is creating classes inside your Storyboard. For instance if you add a view in your screenshot, it will only be "installed" for "Compact x Regular class" devices. Also any frame adjustment, new constraint, etc., will be device class-specific. This is not the correct answer.

Comment: @Rivera please provide a correct one then, because nor the OP nor me were able to select any device preview option, and still, this option I mention is able to help despite preview inside storyboard being not available, since it setups device dimensions that resemble several kinds of real devices. So it may have been good enough for the OP intent, as it's for me.

Comment: @Rivera if you have some explanation about why and how to fix what's mentioned by return-true answer, you could provide an answer or improve return-true's one, and then, we would have a correct one. As this is the most helpful one being provided, I guess it's the correct one for now.

Answer (score 5):

In the storyboard, open the assistant editor.

[image]

Then, top left in the assistant window, choose "Preview" instead of "Automatic".

[image]

Now you can see the preview on different iOS devices (add devices with "+" bottom left)

Comment: Sometimes the dropdown menu to choose "Preview" won't show up probably due to an Xcode bug. Choosing a regular source code file and back is a workaround.